# Why is fingerprint authentication so complicated / slow?

Tags: boot, xubuntu, login, 19.10, fingerprint-reader

Booting the system takes:

1. Swiping my finger on the (lighted up) fingerprint reader. → LED on the fingerprint reader goes out.
2. Select my user.
3. Swiping my finger on the (lighted up again) fingerprint reader again.
4. Select *Sign In*.

Returning from the lock screen takes:

1. Entering my password.
2. Selecting *Unlock...*. → Label *Checking...* appears in the login dialog.
3. **Waiting about 10(!) seconds** until the LED on the fingerprint reader goes on.
4. Swiping my finger on the fingerprint reader.

or:

2. → 3. → 4. → 1. → 2.

In Windows 7 it takes:

to boot and login all-in-one:

1. Swiping my finger on the fingerprint reader.

to return from the lock screen:

1. Swiping my finger on the fingerprint reader.

**UPDATE**

I can comprehend that the two-factor authentication at unlock is more secure on a system that's already up and running. However, is there a setting to avoid the password input and just use the FP? (If somebody else gets his hands on my computer without my finger(s) in the near vicinity I have bigger problems than single-factor authentication anyway.)

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect from us? "Waiting about 10(!) seconds" is that your only problem? If so: investigate why it takes 10 second and file a bug report. "Selecting Unlock" not sure as I don't have FP: is this with or without the normal lock active? if with: what about turning off normal lock screen? That would eliminate 1 extra step

Comment: @Rinzwind An answer to the question in the title. It's not my only problem. Asking if someone possibly found something is the very nature of Q&A sites, isn't it? Don't know if this rule is still respected nowadays but I learned more than 3 decades ago: Everything that takes more than 3 seconds without reaction in an UI is bad UX. And this made and still makes perfectly sense to me (from both user and dev perspective). There is just one lock screen here and it's the same as the one before activating the FP reader – apart from the FP driver apparently intercepting the unlock in the background.

Comment: well the thing is: only a developer of this package is probably likely to answer this. 10 seconds is a lot. I would consider that possibly to be a bug not a feature :)